# use LVCL from http://synopse.info in delphi xe2

Tags: delphi

I am trying to reduce the EXE sixe by using the LVCL from http://synopse.info 
Is it possible to use this library in D XE2?

Comment: This isn't a valid question, as the majority of the content is in an external link. If the link disappears in the future or is changed, your question will become meaningless and therefore useless to future SO readers. It's also not much good in a site search here. Can you find a way to edit it so there's more useful information in the question itself, including what you've tried so far that isn't working and and explanation of in which way it's not working? Thanks. :)

Comment: What is the full list of VCL components that your app requires? Does LVCL cover it?

Comment: @Ken, my intentions are clear. I just wanted to get some help on the issue I am facing. Never thought some people have weird objections on the contents..

Comment: Not a "wierd objection" - think about it. "I'm using <Some Control Package Or Application That Some People Might Not Know About><Some Link>, and I want to know <Something>". What happens if "Some Link" disappears, or "Some Controls or Application" stops being supported, and all the info is gone. What use would this question be then? Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - questions consisting of mostly off-site information aren't appropriate. If that's wierd, discuss it with the site designers on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). BTW, 'i before e except after c' - it's "wierd". :)

Comment: Also note I was not the one that downvoted. I asked you to edit it to provide info instead so it would become something useful. I also didn't vote to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I use the LVCL directly from the personal site of A. Bouchez, [here](http://bouchez.info/lvcl.html).*

The short answer is NO, not out of the box. The LVCL is not unicode compatible, so you'll have to edit it to make it so. I suspect you'll run into further issues beyond that, as the VCL parts you use that are *not* included in the LVCL might have evolved to a point where the LVCL components aren't compatible with them anymore.

Comment: Paul, Thanks for the wise comments.
I agree with you, when i try to use those components in D XE2 project, i encountered numerous issues.